# Unable to install Reporting Services 2017

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, windows-10

I've a computer with Windows 10 and SQL Server 2017 Standard installed. I'm trying to install Reporting Services (I've noticed that now it's a standalone installer), but when I execute the installer (downloaded from the Microsoft website), the process is opened but after 3-4 seconds it closes whitout any screen or message.

I've .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed (the minimum requirement is 4.5.2)

Any hint?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Anything logged to event viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft just release a Version 15.0.2.278 today which I think it's the problem:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252

I think we will have to wait a new release or find the old one in 14.0.600.490...

Edit 01/10/2018: We are back to version 14.0.600.490 now...